# Transparent API GPU acceleration with EmguCV

Tags: opencv, gpu, emgucv, hardware-acceleration, opencv3.1

I've already tested Transparent API GPU Acceleration with OpenCV 3.1 by replacing any 'Mat' by 'UMat'. But for some reason, I need to use EmguCV and C#. Since it's a wrapper to OpenCV it should be possible to use the same acceleration. I searched the web but I can't find the way to do this.

Comment: It seems that EmguCV [exposes `UMat`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.2.0/document/html/54fae358-0713-57d1-9195-fd47e5c82659.htm)...

Comment: Yes it does. but the problem is, most functions in EmguCV only accept Image type not Mat or UMat. and even in those which doe's, I don't see any performance boost by using UMat. @DanMašek